# Do Upgrades to "Power Bonus" affect an Engineers Drone?

Tags: mass-effect-3

You can get a lot of upgrades in ME3 that give a "Power Bonus". Since I kinda see the Drone as a "Power", I would assume the stats of the spawned Drone get a Bonus if you stack power? 
But since you cannot actually see it, I can only guess. So, does someone know for sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

Skills and armour (Inferno armour, Umbra Visor, etc) that give a power bonus will increase the damage done by your drones.

Comment: And you know this how? If you don't mind asking.

Comment: Through testing, I have played the Mass Effect series *extensively* and it's quite obvious that drones are doing more damage when you have a full set of Serrice Council armour on.